# Is it possible to configure Windows 10 to shut down or re-start after too many failed login attempts?

Tags: windows, windows-10, veracrypt, brute-force, windows-hello

- My laptop's C-drive is encrypted with VeraCrypt and a very strong password. But, my Windows Hello password is quite weak.
- If an attacker gets my laptop while it is running but Windows is locked, or the laptop is in sleep mode, I would like to prevent the attacker from brute-forcing or guessing my Windows Hello password.
- If Windows shuts down or re-starts (or locks until manually re-started by the user/attacker) after a few failed login attempts, this would be elegantly solved, because after a re-start the attacker woud be prompted to enter the very strong VeraCrypt password.

Comment: [This guide](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Unencrypted%20Data%20in%20RAM.html) explains: "Furthermore, as Microsoft does not provide any appropriate API for handling hibernation and shutdown, master keys used for system encryption cannot be reliably (and are not) erased from RAM when the computer hibernates, is shut down or restarted." As such, even a restart does not stop an attacker from reading the Veracrypt keys while the computer is running.

Comment: Thx for the comment. Fair enough, but this kind of direct RAM attack seems pretty sophisticated. I don't guard state-secrets, so I am trying not to go over-the-top.

Comment: Your account would be disabled after the appropriate number of attempts even with your Windows Hello pin.  As for Windows automatically restarting or shutting down, after a certain number of attempts to access an account, that isn't a feature of Windows at this time.

Comment: What exactly is a "disabled" account? How can the actual user get access again to his/her disabled Windows account?

Answer (score 0):

Something like [SpyLog](https://github.com/moteus/lua-spylog) would allow you to perform scripted actions based upon log entries.

A full **shutdown** will drop dynamic ram contents quickly, you just need to make sure that Windows is configured to actually shutdown as this is often not the default in laptops in order to give a quick startup.